# Rounded corner text field with Rebol 2 / Rebol 3?

Tags: rebol

A tiny detail that is hugely important in today's design is rounded corner field especially for Mobile style. How to do this in Rebol 2, is there any more facilities to do so in Rebol 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically in R2, but it's straightforward to apply a bitmap with rounded corners and the ever useful 'extend effect.

Comment: can you give sample code or is there some example in rebol.org thanks ?

Comment: view layout [field btn-dn.png effect 'extend edge none colors none]

Answer (score 1):

You btn  instead of button. See http://rebol2.blogspot.it/2012/07/all-vid-styles.html  for more details.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.